# How can I update adapter data when the data is recieved from internet

Tags: android

I've got an adapter and an asynctask. I would like to update the data for the adapter when android recieves data from the internet.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use list or ArrayList for data

> ex. `List<String> movieList = new ArrayList<>();`

2) pass the list to adapter constructor and set adapter to listview or recycleview

3) get data from internet and add to list using

> `movieList.add("Thor");`

4) after refresh adapter using

> `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

note:- mAdapter was a adapter object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Android Architecture Components.

Specifically for this task, check out LiveData

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html

and ViewModel.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html